# Image Rotation in Three Dimensions (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate a 2D image in Matlab xyz 3-D space. I want to rotate the image *I* by an angle *θ=i* about the x-axis. I am doing this by means of multiplication with the rotation matrix (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions)):

This is my code:

```
x = linspace(-1,1,size(I,1));
[x0,y0,z0] = meshgrid(x,x,1);
R = [1 0 0; 0 cosd(-i) -sind(-i); 0 sind(-i) cosd(-i)];
xy = [x0(:),y0(:), z0(:)]*R';
X = reshape(xy(:,1),size(x0));
Y = reshape(xy(:,2),size(y0));
Z = reshape(xy(:,3),size(z0));
rotatedI = interp3(x0,y0,z0,I,X,Y,Z, 'nearest');
rotatedI(isnan(rotatedI)) = 0;
```

The error that I am getting is in the interpolation line:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each
dimension.
```

So what exactly is the problem here and how can I fix it?

I am confused because this code works fine when specialized to two dimensions. Any explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that your input z grid `z0` contains a single value (`1`), while your desired z grid `Z` contains multiple values. therefore there is no way to interpolate this single value into multiple ones.

you can assign the input z grid with multiple values so that it will be possible to interpolate.

```
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
I = cat(3,I,I,I);
i = 10;
x = linspace(-1,1,size(I,1));
[x0,y0,z0] = meshgrid(x,x,-1:1); % 3 z values
R = [1 0 0; 0 cosd(-i) -sind(-i); 0 sind(-i) cosd(-i)];
xy = [x0(:),y0(:), z0(:)]*R;
X = reshape(xy(:,1),size(x0));
Y = reshape(xy(:,2),size(y0));
Z = reshape(xy(:,3),size(z0));
rotatedI = interp3(x0,y0,z0,I,X,Y,Z, 'nearest');
rotatedI(isnan(rotatedI)) = 0;
imshow(rotatedI);
```

[image]

in addition, you can use `rotx`, `roty`, and `rotz` to generate rotation matrices easily.

**UPDATE**

if you want to rotate the image 2D plane in the 3D space you don't need to use interpolation and can do something like:

```
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
i = 10;
x = linspace(-1,1,size(I,1));
[x0,y0,z0] = meshgrid(x,x,-1:1); % 3 z values
[x0,y0,z0] = meshgrid(x,x,1); % 3 z values
R = [1 0 0; 0 cosd(-i) -sind(-i); 0 sind(-i) cosd(-i)];
xy = [x0(:),y0(:), z0(:)]*R;
X = reshape(xy(:,1),size(x0));
Y = reshape(xy(:,2),size(y0));
Z = reshape(xy(:,3),size(z0));
warp(X,Y,Z,I);
grid on
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But the resulting image is superimposed on the original. It doesn't really get rotated in 3-D world coordinates. Is it possible to somehow achieve this by using the code in conjunction with 'image3' on Matlab's FEX? So far this is what the image looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDi9m.jpg

Comment: the z dimension of the 2D image rotated with `interp3` is actually the **color** dimension (RGB), therefore the result seems as "superimposed" images. if you want to rotate the image 2D plane in the 3D space you can look at my edit

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. One last question: the current code rotates the image around its edge. Is there a simple modification that can make the image rotate around its center point? Or do we need to center the images manually by moving them? For instance, for 0° and 90° the center of the images do not coincide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM55y.jpg

Comment: use the value 0 for z coordinates.